# Interpolation in a regex

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to add interpolation in a regex.

what I have right now is `var re = /212.129.52.45/gi`
what i need is to replace the `212.129.52.45` with `ip_appress`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the RegExp constructor, but be careful to escape the `.` character.

You’ll want to call RegExp with this:

```
const re = new RegExp(‘212\\.129\\.52\\.45’,’g’)
```

You can do that by using `ip_address.replace(/\./g,’\\.’)`.

If you do not escape the `.`, it will match any character in that position.

Comment: Probably not; that’s what I get for doing an edit on my phone.

Comment: @DaniloVenticinque , this works so ty. but there is a slight problem where if input `217.138.216.62` is the full string in the request, `217.138.216.6` will also return `true`. How could I prevent that?

Comment: Good point.Try adding “(?!\\d)” to the escaped ip_address string you’re using in the RegExp constructor; that should prevent a false positive when there are additional digits.

Answer (score 7):

use the [`Regexp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) instead

```js
const ip_address = '217.138.216.62'

const re = new RegExp(`^${ip_address.replace(/\./g, '\\.')}$`, 'gi')

console.log(re.test('217.138.216.62'))

console.log(re.test('217.138.216.6'))
```

Here we are using [Boundary-type Assertions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions) (`^` and `$`) to match when only the full pattern is found from start-to-end.